# Android 9.0: keyStore.getEntry logs ServiceSpecificException (code 7)

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, logcat

I have an issue with `KeyStore.getEntry` in a project when running the emulator with Android 9 (API 28).
The problem is the same when running the sample code from here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicAndroidKeyStore

When clicking on the 'sign' button in the UI, logcat shows the following exception (logged, not leading to a crash in the app):

```
09-07 14:35:37.535 16583-16583/com.example.android.basicandroidkeystore W/KeyStore: KeyStore exception
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 7)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
        at android.security.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.get(IKeystoreService.java:786)
        at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:195)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetCertificateChain(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:118)
        at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:484)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1560)
        at com.example.android.basicandroidkeystore.BasicAndroidKeyStoreFragment.signData(BasicAndroidKeyStoreFragment.java:234)
        at com.example.android.basicandroidkeystore.BasicAndroidKeyStoreFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(BasicAndroidKeyStoreFragment.java:102)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2394)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:3326)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:344)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:386)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1237)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:776)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:148)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:923)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:913)
        at android.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:617)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:147)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Does anyone know why this exception happens, and how to prevent it? The app seems to run fine, but I'm worried this might lead to a crash in a future release of Android…

Comment: Looks like an issue was filed, though I'm not sure if that one comment has a reproducible test case or not: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113559499. If you can update that issue with a clear way to reproduce the problem, perhaps it can get looked at.

Comment: It looks like it might have something to do with Android P's API blacklist https://github.com/adorsys/secure-storage-android/issues/30#issuecomment-413798444

Comment: Thanks! I commented on that issue and added link to the official Google sample as reproducible test code. Hope this will get fixed in a future release.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024752/android-p-keystore-exception-android-os-servicespecificexception/52295484#52295484