# Android Keystore crashes , majority on Samsung devices, Android 8 and 8.1, at Android application start

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo, android-keystore

Getting `NullPointerException`.
At Android application start.

In application, some user related sensitive information is encrypted or decrypted using KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry before storing-retrieving respectively.

Initially (at application startup) while trying to set up the things(like in this case Keystore utility) the app try to get the KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry using private-key, Certificate, and some attributes, somehow for the **Android 8.0** and majority for **Samsung devices**(as per Google play Error stats) the Certificate is passed as a null, which is why its explicitly throwing NPE.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.<init> (KeyStore.java:559)
  at java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.<init> (KeyStore.java:526)
  at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry (KeyStoreSpi.java:519)
  at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry (KeyStore.java:1621)
  at com.compant.xyz.data.KeyStoreUtils.getPrivateKey (KeyStoreUtils.java:68)
  at com.compant.xyz.data.KeyStoreUtils.<init> (KeyStoreUtils.java:53)
  at com.compant.xyz.data.KeyStoreManager.<init> (KeyStoreManager.java:29)
  at com.compant.xyz.injection.module.DependencyModule.provideKeystore (DependencyModule.java:52)
  at com.compant.xyz.injection.module.DependencyModule_ProvideKeystoreFactory.get (DependencyModule_ProvideKeystoreFactory.java:19)
  at com.compant.xyz.injection.module.DependencyModule_ProvideKeystoreFactory.get (DependencyModule_ProvideKeystoreFactory.java:8)
  at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get (DoubleCheck.java:47)
  at com.compant.xyz.COMPANYApplication_MembersInjector.injectMembers (COMPANYApplication_MembersInjector.java:34)
  at com.compant.xyz.COMPANYApplication_MembersInjector.injectMembers (COMPANYApplication_MembersInjector.java:9)
  at com.compant.xyz.injection.component.DaggerDependencyComponent.inject (DaggerDependencyComponent.java:861)
  at com.compant.xyz.COMPANYApplication.initDependency (COMPANYApplication.java:75)
  at com.compant.xyz.COMPANYApplication.onCreate (COMPANYApplication.java:35)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1125)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6062)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1764)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 9 - KeyStore exception android.os.ServiceSpecificException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024752/android-9-keystore-exception-android-os-servicespecificexception)