# KeyStore.getCertificate() floods the log with warnings

Tags: android, android-keystore

Here's a really simple sample code:

```
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
keyStore.load(null)
if (keyStore.getCertificate("foobar") == null) {
     Log.d("kkkkk", "keystore not found")
}
```

Every time I call the getCertificate() method, the KeyStore puts a stacktrace into the log as a warning. Although the code works as expected still it's very frustrating because we use this function very extensively and our log became very hard to read. I experienced this on almost all phone that runs an least Android 9. Here is the beginning of the stacktrace:

```
2020-03-27 14:34:49.541 26536-26536/com.example.keystoreexceptiontest W/KeyStore: KeyStore exception
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 7)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2085)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.security.keystore.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.get(IKeystoreService.java:978)
        at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:236)
        at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:225)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetCertificate(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:160)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getCertificate(KeyStore.java:1120)
```

After some search I found many similar issues but most of them recommend exactly this solution to solve the problem, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024752/android-9-keystore-exception-android-os-servicespecificexception)

Can you recommend something to get rid of those warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question ! If possible, you should mark your own question as the accepted answer.

I had the very same issue, and followed the link you provided. Inside [the answer from NullPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072898/7490633) (that is older than your question), there is this sentence that helped me to figure out what is happening :

> This means, that there is no private key and you should first create and store a keypair before you search for it in the key store.

To rephrase it : if you search for a certificate that doesn't exists, you'll have this annoying log.
You should first look for the private key (using keyStore.getKey) and if it exists you may look for the certificate.

To rewrite it, it may looks like this :

```
val privateKey = keyStore.getKey(keyAlias,null);
if (privateKey != null) {
    publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias)?.publicKey;
}
else
{
    createKey();
}
```

Comment: Hi mgueydan! Sorry for the late reaction! So the implementation in the real app is way more complex but I've checked it and the certificate is never null (otherwise the app would crash) and we always check the existence of the alias before the invocation of getCertificate() with keyStore.containsAlias() method. However, I see that the private key is in fact null in some cases.  So I'll definitely look after how's this possible. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: Btw I filed a bug to Google.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152844288