# Persist certificate for subsequent requests

Tags: android, kotlin, ssl

I am using X.509 certificates (`X509Certificate`) with my OkHttpClient in order to authenticate my requests. I have a remote API that generates the certificates. Instead of recreating that certificate for each request, I would like to cache it and use as long as it's valid.

Is saving them in the KeyStore the correct approach? Here is my current implementation, I just want to know if I'm on the right track. Is the keystore intended to be used like this?

Initialization:

```
private var keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {
    load(null)
}
```

Set certificate:

```
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate)
```

Get certificate:

```
return keyStore.getCertificate(alias) as X509Certificate
```

It seems to be working, with the exception of that I get an error in logcat when fetching the certificate: [KeyStore exception android.os.ServiceSpecificException: (code 7) at ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024752/android-9-keystore-exception-android-os-servicespecificexception). Am I on the right track or am I misusing the keystore?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#UnknownCa) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

Comment: @SiddharthSharma Looks promising, thanks